# On the parity of $\left\lfloor{\frac{3^n}{2^n}}\right\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a_n=(-1)^{\left\lfloor{\frac{3^n}{2^n}}\right\rfloor}$ and $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k.$$

Is it true that $s_n\le 0$ for all $n\geq 1$ ?  (This is true for $n\le 100000$.)

In other words, odd numbers are always more than even numbers on the sequence $\left\lfloor{\frac{3^n}{2^n}}\right\rfloor$.
This is unexpected, I think they should be roughly equal, and even numbers will exceed odd numbers sometimes.

Comment: I like the word "odevity", even though it's not English. :-) https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=42739 The question itself is interesting, I thought the distribution of *the fractional* parts of $\left(\frac32\right)^n$ was the one we don't know much about...

Comment: @preferred_anon If I'm not mistaken it starts $1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, \dots$.

Comment: @RaviFernando You're right, I'll remove my comment!

Comment: Each ratio $a/b$ has its own behavior. There are ratios like $7/5$ that give more evens than odds at least for $n<10000$. Others like $4/3$ start odd-heavy and turn to even-heavy.

Comment: If my numerical testing is correct this is not true for all $n$; the first time where $s_n>0$ is $n=331523$, with $165762$ even and $165761$ odd numbers

Comment: Just an idea: $3 = 2+1$, thus $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n = \frac{(2+1)^n}{2^n} \overset{\text{binomial}}{=} \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^{-k}$

Comment: @qfwfq I think the integer part of $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$ is even iff the fractional part of $\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, so it would still be somewhat connected to fractional parts...

Comment: Conjecture: for any sequence of $1$s and $-1$s, there exists a $c$ such that $(-1)^{\lfloor c3^n/2^n\rfloor}$ realizes that sequence

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger if that is true then there would be a $c$ such that the sequence has only even terms, and then the fractional parts of $\frac{1}{2}c\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$ are all less than $\frac{1}{2}$, so $\frac{1}{2}c$ would be a $Z$-number: [Mahler's 3/2 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler%27s_3/2_problem) conjectures that no $Z$-number exists

Comment: @hgmath That's _open_? That's surprising!

Comment: I wonder if it's useful to think about "base 3/2". ("Base" as in binary, decimal, etc) I know fractional bases have been studied. What's 2 in base 3/2?

Comment: How does one even find the value of $a_n$ for given $n$?

Comment: @donaastor: use Pari/GP; `N=100; print(floor((3/2)^N) % 2)` . You can go fairly large `N`.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms So, the algorithm is basically "calculate (3/2)^n" and see the last digit? That can't be true. The complexity is too big. You could make few thousands by that. But not 500000 values of a_n

Comment: @donaastor - surely. Depending on software-implementation there might be a better( faster, less-memory-consumtive) procedure. For instance I tried another option via the internal `binary()`representation, but surprisingly this was a bit slower. Using Pari/GP for the 64bit-OS there's no problem to go up to N of millions...(I'm not aware of any analytical shortcut, though)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms You are not answering my question. I am concerned exactly about those "better procedures". Maybe you can calculate a single a_n where n is of millions, but you can't calculate all a_n where n goes from 1 to million.

Comment: @donaastor - I tried up to $N=10\,000$ on a 2012-Laptop. This needed about $28$ secs. I tried it just to get a basic feeling, and don't want to invest more time in it, but measuring time for $N=2^{10},2^{11},2^{12},...$ as far as your patience allows and then extrapolating is perhaps interesting. protocol: `gettime();a=1.0;for(N=1,10000,a*=1.5;b=binary(a)[1];w=b[#b]);gettime()
`  `\\ %324 = 28346 \\ milli-seconds`

Comment: @donaastor: one more protocol, using @hgmaths description: `gettime();a=1;su=0;for(N=1,331524,a*=3;w=a>>N;if(w%2,su--,su++));[su,gettime()]` gives `%339 = [2, 31762]` : sum=$2$ is positive, time is about $31$ secs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but here are some results from computer simulation:

While the sequence $s_n$ starts out being negative for quite some time (as mentioned in the question, for more than the first $100\,000$ terms), it does reach positive values eventually. The first time this happens is for $n=331\,523$; there we have $165\,762$ even and $165\,761$ odd numbers. So the answer to the question would be **no**.

After that it continues to alternate between positive and negative values.

See this plot of $s_n$ for $n$ up to $1\,000\,000$:
[image: graph]

Here is how it continues up to $5\,000\,000$:
[image: graph2]

Of course it would be nice if this could be verified without computer help... or to see a theoretical description of the asympotic behavior of $s_n$...

Comment: How did you calculate these sequences?

Comment: @donaastor this particular sequence is pretty nice for computer calculation because you don't need to divide anything at all (that would by far be the most expensive operation). Instead we can do everything in integer arithmetic. The parity of the integer part of $3^n/2^n$ can be obtained as the **(n+1)-th digit in the binary representation of $3^n$** (counting from the right). (Dividing by $2^n$ is right shift by $n$, parity is last digit.) Now we can just iteratively calculate the powers of $3$ (note that multiplying by $3$ is just doubling and adding) and take the appropiate digits

Comment: Time complexity is quadratic; getting to the first positive $s_n$ takes a few seconds, the first million $n$ about a minute

Comment: This was exactly what I was asking for. Thank you. I could have thinked of an algorithm like that, but it still surprises me that all that computation can be done in under a minute. Fantastic :) I thought that there might be some trickier method that everybody considered trivial haha

Comment: @hgmath How do you store a number so large as $3^{1,000,000}$ though? Or do you only compute up to the $n+1$th digit in the binary representation? Any sample code would be really helpful :)

Comment: @chaos *Storing* these numbers is really not a problem, since $\log_2(3)<1.6$ the number $3^{1\,000\,000}$ takes less than $1\,600\,000$ bits which is $200$ kilobytes... Of course the arithmetic operations get more expensive with longer numbers

Comment: About only computing part of the digits, I have thought a bit about it but I think that's not really possible in this case. And anyway it wouldn't have saved that much really (e.g. we want to get the $1\,000\,000$-th digit of a ~$1\,600\,000$-bit number...)